# What does 'count' mean in Master API of Assign a file key?

Tags: seaweedfs

I was reading this link about api:
`https://github.com/chrislusf/seaweedfs/wiki/Master-Server-API#assign-a-file-key`
but I didn't understand what will "count" option do.
Can you give an example about this option please?

```
count: how many file ids to assign. Use <fid>_1, <fid>_2 for the assigned additional file ids. e.g. 3,01637037d6_1, 3,01637037d6_2
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you may want to reserve multiple file ids.

E.g., one picture may have multiple versions.

In a file id, <volume_id, key, cookie>.

For _1, _2, they will be translated to <volume_id, key+1, cookie>, <volume_id, key+2, cookie>